# Targeting multiple elements when going from .click() to .on() for Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to switch from

```
$('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
```

to `.on()` because I have content which is loaded dynamically. I'm having issues including including the `$wrapper` variable, and I'm not sure where to put it. The jquery documentation did not seem clear to me how to target multiple items when one is a variable.

I tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper, function() {
$($wrapper).on('click', '.multi-field .remove-field', function() {
$(document).on('click', '.multi-field .remove-field' $wrapper, function() {
```

What should I read up to understand how to select multiple elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nearly there. 
This should work for dynamically added elements. I'm guessing the `$wrapper` element is an already wrapped jQuery element.

```js
var $wrapper = $("body");

$wrapper.on("click", ".multi-field .remove-field", function(e) {
    console.log({_this: this});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-field"><button class="remove-field">Remove field</button></div>
```